# How to pass only the date to the database (without passing the time) using react-datetime picker

Tags: reactjs, react-datetime

How to pass only the date to the database (without passing the time) using react-datetime picker.

Currently in my code it will pass both date and time to the backend like this (2021-09-07T18:30:00.000Z).

I want to pass only the date like (2021-09-07) without the time.
using react-datetime picker

please help me!

```
                         <ReactDatetime
                            inputProps={{
                              placeholder: "MM/DD/YY",
                            }}
                            dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                            timeFormat={false}
                            onChange={(value) =>
                              formik.handleChange({
                                target: {
                                  name: "date_of_the_event",
                                  value,
                                },
                              })
                            }
                            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                            value={formik.values.date_of_the_event}
                          />
```

Comment: Don't know about formik, but usually you should be able to grab only the date part using vanilla js a library like momenjs. Grab only the date part from that 'value' parameter.

Comment: Cast or convert `value` to a string `dateStr` if need be, then do something like `dateStr.split("T")[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

In the handleChange method, you can format the date like this.

`` const formattedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}` ``

If you use a library like momentjs, you can simply format the date like this

`const formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');`

Answer (score 0):

you can get your date as a string with that format by using the below statement

```
   const formattedDate =  date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' })
```

If you need to swap date and month use `'en-US'`

If you want any custom format get one by one and append it like below

```
 const formattedDate = 
 `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}`
```